# Is there a way to remove the space in navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to remove the space with padding or margin it is not working.

[image]

It is this blue region. I don't know the command or name for it.

[image]

I just want to reduce the spacing dont want to completely get rid of it

Code

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 10%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00000028;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.nav-links,
li,
a {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}

.nav-links,
li,
a:hover {
  color: #0052FF;
}

.login-signup {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.login-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
}

.login-btn:hover {
  color: #0052FF;
}

.signup-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0052FF;
  border-style: solid;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #0052FF;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

.signup-btn:hover {
  background-color: #0044d7;
  border-color: #0044d7;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png')}}" alt="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="login-signup">
    <a href="#"><button class="login-btn">Log In</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="signup-btn">Sign Up</button></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is related to this css code:

```
.nav-links,
li,
a {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}
```

change margin.